# The differential of the inverse equals the inverse of the differential

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

If S $\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ and S' $\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ regular surfaces and g:S $\rightarrow$ S' is a diffeomorphism and p $\in$ S then the

$Dg^{-1}|_{g(p)}=(Dg|_p)^{-1}$

Is it necessary that g is a diffeomorphism?

I don't really know how to approach the first part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Write $g^{-1}\circ g = \mathrm{id}$ and use the chain-rule at the point $p$. (The diffeomorphism condition is here so that $g^{-1}$ is smooth and it makes sense to talk about its differential.)

Comment: @Didier Thank you, i think i got it